# How to show/hide bottom navigation bar in some screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

This [blog](https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1) shows how to preserve page state using `PageStorage`

This [blog](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf) shows multiple navigation for each screen. The bottom nav bar here persist on all screens

But how do you make `BottomNavigationBar` show/hide in some screens? Say, login/register/successful screens? Tried to create a stateful widget for `BottomNavigationBar` but selectedIndex for the nav bar gets reset every time I use it. I can't seem to make it work.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('app_screen'),
      bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNavigationController(),
    );
  }
}
```

`app_bottom_navigation_controller.dart`

```
class AppBottomNavigationController extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppBottomNavigationControllerState createState() =>
      _AppBottomNavigationControllerState();
}

class _AppBottomNavigationControllerState
    extends State<AppBottomNavigationController> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> pages = [];
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  void initState() {
    pages.addAll([
      HomeScreen(
        key: PageStorageKey('home_screen'),
      ),
      SearchScreen(
        key: PageStorageKey('search_screen'),
      ),
      AccountScreen(
        key: PageStorageKey('account_screen'),
      )
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[currentIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(currentIndex),
    );
  }

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: Text('Search'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text('Account'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Then under `account.dart` screen, I have `account_bag.dart` and `account_successful.dart` screens. I would like to have my `account_bag.dart` screen to have the bottom nav bar while the `account_successful.dart` does not.

Comment: Can you drop your present code?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi edited my post

Comment: can you add your account_bag and account_successful files

Comment: Files only contain simple widget text on it.